# Добавление и удаление ключей из словаря

Tags: python, словари

Всем добрый вечер!

Есть словарь:

```
fruits = {
'apple': ['15'], 
'orange': ['25'], 
'melon': []}
```

После ввода пользователем определённых команд (add и del) нужно добавить новый введённый юзером ключ (предположим, `'pineapple'`) и удалить существующий (только если директория пустая, как в случае с `'melon'`). В результате, и там, и там нужно вывести обновлённый список ключей (без значений).

В теории я знаю, как добавлять и удалять ключи в словаре, используя команды `.update` и `.pop`. Но я не могу сообразить, как добавить/удалить ключ, введённый непосредственно пользователем по команде.

Заранее спасибо за подсказки!

Comment: Имеешь ввиду парсинг команды? или что?

Comment: Добавить пустой пустой список по ключу введенному пользователем: `fruit = input(); fruits[fruit]=[]` Удалить: `del(fruits[fruit])`

Comment: Имею в виду вот, что: пользователь вводит команду add, вводит pineapple и в результате получает что-то вроде: "Текущий список фруктов: apple, orange, melon, pineapple".

Comment: @VeronikaZalesskaya получить ключи словаря - `fruits.keys()`. Перечисить их через запятую - `', '.join(fruits.keys())`

Comment: @insolor Спасибо!! Мне казалось, что я делаю то же самое, но я не присваивала значение. Наверное, поэтому ничего не выходило.

Comment: @VeronikaZalesskaya если разобрались, можно добавить свой ответ

Answer (score 1):

Всё вышло, всё работает:

```
fruits = {
'apple': ['15'], 
'orange': ['25'], 
'melon': []}

p = input('Введите команду')
if p == 'add':
    fruit = input('Введите новый фрукт: ')
    fruits[fruit]=[]
    print(', '.join(fruits.keys()))

if p == 'del':
    fruit = input('Введите ненужный фрукт: ')
    del(fruits[fruit])
    print(', '.join(fruits.keys()))
```

Но есть парочка дополнительных условий, с которыми тоже нужна помощь:

1. Если фрукт уже существует (при добавлении) или его нет в списке (при удалении), нужно вывести соответствующую команду.
2. Если у ключа есть значение, удалять его нельзя. То есть удалить можно только ключ с пустым списком значений.

Не понимаю, какие if в данных случаях задавать. И можно ли создать общую функцию , чтобы не раздувать код?

Comment: 1 - наличие ключа в словаре можно проверять с помощью `fruit in fruits` (будет True, если ключ есть в словаре), `fruit not in fruits` (будет True, если ключа нет в словаре). 2 - тут перед удалением есть смысл проверить, что ключ есть в словаре, ну и проверять длину списка по этому ключу `len(fruits[fruit]) > 0`

Answer (score 1):

Вот такой код должен работать:

```
fruits = { 'apple': ['15'], 'orange': ['25'],  'melon': []}

def menu(p):
    if p == 'as':
        return add_fruit(input('Введите фрукт: '))
    elif p == 'ds':
        return rem_fruit(input('Введите фрукт: '))
    elif p == 's':
        return get_fruit(input('Введите номер фрукта: '))
    
def add_fruit(name):
    if name in fruits:
        return 'Такой фрукт уже существует'
    fruits[name] = []
    return 'Фрукт добавлен. Текущий список: ' + ', '.join(fruits.keys())

def rem_fruit(name):
    if name in fruits:
        if fruits[name]:
            return 'На складе ещё есть фрукты'
        del fruits[name]
        return 'Фрукт удалён. Текущий список: ' + ', '.join(fruits.keys())
    return 'Такого фрукта нет на складе'

def get_fruit(number):
    res = list(filter(lambda e: number in e[1], fruits.items()))
    return res[0] if res else 'Такой фрукт не существует'
    

p = input('Введите команду: ') 
print(menu(p))
```

Comment: Вместо `if name in fruits.keys():` возможно просто `if name in fruits:` т.к. словари итеруются по ключам.

Comment: @n1tr0xs  Спасибо! Разобралась, почему у меня не срабатывало. Еще один момент. Мне нужно по значению узнать, в какой категории находится фрукт. Я использовала функцию `def_fruit(number)` - `return list(filter(lambda e: number in e[1], fruits.items()))[0]`  Но не предусмотрела условие: если вводимое значение не существует - должно выходить соответствующее предупреждение. Пытаюсь его ввести в функцию через `if number not in fruits.values()`, но получаю какую-то фигню. Как это условие грамотно вписать в функцию?

Comment: @VeronikaZalesskaya что-то я не очень понимаю какой должен быть результат

Comment: @MarianD спасибо, запямятовал

Comment: @n1tr0xs сейчас покажу отдельным ответом

Comment: @VeronikaZalesskaya дополнил код

Comment: Функция `get_fruit()` лишняя — вы её нигде не применили. К функции `rem_fruit()`: Что, когда такой фрукт в словаре не существует?

Comment: @MarianD функцию ```get_fruit``` применяется внутри функции ```menu```, если пользователь ввел 's', а функцию ```rem_fruit``` сейчас поправлю, спасибо за замечание

Comment: Команда `s` в меню вами придумана, и тоже смысл значений-списков в словаре `fruits`. Что когда два фрукта имеют те же самые списки? Лучше всего бы было удалить такую команду, и тоже изменить ваши команды `asý и `ds` на `add` и `del` (как это требуется в вопросе).

Comment: `try...except...` достаточно сложно — почему не просто применить `if name in fruits:`?

Comment: @MarianD согласен, тут лишнее

Answer (score 0):

Вы это имеете ввиду?

```
b = {'a':1,
    'b':2,
    'c':3}
zet = input("New key: ")
b.update({zet:[]})
b.pop(zet)
```

Answer (score 0):

Итак, я всё ещё мучаюсь со своими фруктами. Вот, что есть:

```
fruits = {
'apple': ['15'], 
'orange': ['25'], 
'melon': []}

def add_fruit(name):
    fruits[name] = []
    if name != fruits.keys():
        print('Фрукт добавлен. Текущий список: ', ', '.join(fruits.keys()))
    else:
        print('Такой фрукт уже существует')
    
def rem_fruit(name):
    fruits[name] = []
    if len(fruits[name]) == 0: 
        del(fruits[name])
        print('Фрукт удалён. Текущий список: ',', '.join(fruits.keys()))
    else:
        print('На складе ещё есть фрукты')

p = input('Введите команду: ')
if p == 'as':
    print(add_fruit(input('Введите фрукт: ')))

if p == 'ds':
    print(rem_fruit(input('Введите фрукт: ')))
```

Проблемы:

1. У меня выполняется только условие по if. Почему else не срабатывает?
2. Куда вставлять return?

Есть ли вариант ещё больше сократить код?

Comment: `if name != fruits.keys()` - что вы так проверяете? Наверное вы имеете в виду `if name not in fruits.keys()`, что в Python 3 можно записать как `if name not in fruits`

Comment: *«Куда вставлять return?»* - никуда, неявный `return` всегда в конце функции (возвращает `None`, но вы это не используете).

Answer (score 0):

Итак, есть всё тот же словарь:

```
fruits = {
'apple': ['15'], 
'orange': ['25'], 
'melon': []}
```

Есть функция, которая позволяет найти фрукт по его номеру:

```
def get_fruit(number):
    return list(filter(lambda e: number in e[1], fruits.items()))[0]
```

Используем мы её вот так:

```
p = input('Введите команду: ')
if p == 's':
    print(get_fruit(input('Введите номер фрукта: '))[0])
```

Но есть условие. Если пользователь вводит значение, которого не существует в словаре (к примеру, 33), вместо ошибки должно появиться сообщение "Такого фрукта не существует". Как ввести данное условие в функцию?

Comment: Ну так не берите сразу `[0]` от полученного внутри функции `get_fruit` списка, проверьте внутри функции, не пустой ли получился список и если пустой, выводите эту надпись